# Characterizing The Number of Inversions in A Permutation

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, permutations

There is a known result that states the following about the number of inversions in a permutation. In particular, a permutation has an odd number of inversions if and only if it contains an odd number of even length cycles.

I would like to know if the number of inversions can be further characterized in the case where there is exactly one even length cycle. More precisely, what can we say about the number of inversions if a permutation of size $2^k$ (where $k$ is a positive integer) consists of exactly one cycle of length $2^k$?

Edit: Perhaps an exact formula may not be known, but there may be other interesting properties that help characterize the number of inversions. I am not very familiar with the literature in this area, so any potential references would be appreciated.

Comment: Computing the first ten values of the inversions of single-cycle permutations by enumeration sends us to [OEIS A227404](http://oeis.org/A227404) where a simple formula is given which supposedly is only a conjecture at this time.

Comment: Is this the sum of inversions for all permutations on $n$ elements which consist of a single cycle? I am more interested in, given a permutation which has exactly one cycle of even length (in my case, $2^k$), can we say anything interesting?

Comment: This is interesting to know as well, thank you. I didn't think that such a problem would be conjecture.

Comment: The lowest possible number of inversions in an $n$-cycle of $S_n$ is $n-1$. This is attained for so called [Coxeter elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_element) that are products of the $n-1$ generating 2-cycles $(12), (23),\ldots, (n-1;n)$ in some order. Not all $n$-cycles are Coxeter elements though. There are $(n-1)!$ $n$-cycles in $S_n$, but the number of Coxeter elements is less, because when $n\ge4$ some pairs of generating 2-cycles commute.